# Can I use eGPU over m.2 port?

Tags: gpu, lenovo-laptop, m.2

Can I use an eGPU setup on my laptop (Lenovo IdeaPad 320-14ikd) which only has m.2 (currently used my Bluetooth and WiFi)? it doesn't have Thunderbolt so it won't be possible to use USB C.

Comment: No, not possible.

Comment: Can you use BlueTooth to connect an external GPU to your system?  - No;  Can you use WiFi to connect an external GPU to your system? - No;  What you want will not be possible with the laptop you have.  What you should use, will not work, because you have a laptop

Comment: But you can change wifi and bt card on mini pcie to egpu(used on my old laptop)

Answer (score 0):

In theory, assuming you're willing to give up Bluetooth and Wi-Fi, and have a ribbon cable running out of your laptop case, yes, it is technically possible, and you can find adapters that will let you do this.

In practice, there are a lot of issues with this approach:

- The adapters are generally designed to take regular PCI-e GPUs, which aren't designed to be run outside a case.
- The GPU will need to get its power from somewhere, and an M.2 slot probably won't be able to supply enough for it.
- The long cable will usually result in signal degradation that will have a significant impact on performance (and may impact reliability too).
- A lot of laptop manufacturers (Lenovo included) take particularly draconian measures in their firmware to ensure you're only running hardware they approve of in your system.  As a result, the computer probably won't boot with the GPU plugged in, and M.2 does not support hotplugging in any realistically reliable way.

Comment: I can just fix a psu from an old stationairy pc, and the whitelist is going to be a problem, but there is nothing perfect, lets find how to edit it :) i will hopefully delete the whitelist if there is any

Comment: Will there be any loss of performance(fps)?

Comment: I would advise against messing around with your firmware at that level, one wrong step and you've got a really expensive paperweight.  As far as performance degradation, there will likely be some, but I have no idea how much.

Comment: I will flash the bios using usb bios programer so it should be pretty secure